# How to change position of multiple elements on input

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning, interactive

I'm trying to modify the left parameter of 5 elements with the same id in the negative value of an input element as a percentage. in practice I want that when the input value changes, the left parameter of the 5 elements is equal to the input value but negative and in percentage.

```js
var x = document.getElementById-("input");
   function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById('slide').style.left = x ;
     }
```

```html
<div class="exemple">
      <img id="slide" src="example">
      <img id="slide" src="example">
      <img id="slide" src="example">
      <img id="slide" src="example">
      <img id="slide" src="example">
   </div>
   <input id="inupt" onchange = "myFunction()">
  

</div>
```

Comment: you cannot have multiple elements with the same id. Also what is the expected value for `x`?

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya thank you, I will change the ids, the expected value for x is the value of input

Comment: This looks like a case of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) -- what are you trying to achieve, on the overall level? `img` elements are for content, not decoration.

Comment: @amn it is like a kind of slideshow and I wanted the user to be able to navigate trough the slides (img) with a slider but no worry, now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, your code was really quite the hassle. Please watch your typos the next time! 
This should do the job, i dont know what you are up to exactly, but id advise you to use a framework for sliders.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

  var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides, function(el) {

    el.style.left = "" + x + "px";
  });
}
```

```css
.slide {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="exemple">
  <img class="slide" src="example">
  <img class="slide" src="example">
  <img class="slide" src="example">
  <img class="slide" src="example">
  <img class="slide" src="example">
</div>
<input id="input" onchange="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't have more then one element with the same ID - It make sense cause id's are unique.
2. If you want to manipulate more then one element you can use the class attribute.

I guess you want to achieve something like this (added comments to the js in order to explain):

```js
function myFunction() { // when the input value changes
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('slide'); // this is the images with the class instead of id
var y = document.getElementById('demo').value; // this will take the current value of the input
  for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++) { // this will illitrate all images with the class slide
    x[i].style.left = y+'px'; // this will move all of them left
  }
}
```

```css
img {width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; position: relative;}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="slide" />
  <img class="slide" />
  <img class="slide" />
  <img class="slide" />
  <img class="slide" />
</div>
<input type="number" id="demo" onchange="myFunction()" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you wanted to achieve -

```
<div class="example">
      <img class="slide" src="https://404store.com/2018/09/01/random-small-images43.png">
      <img class="slide" src="https://404store.com/2018/09/01/random-small-images43.png">
      <img class="slide" src="https://404store.com/2018/09/01/random-small-images43.png">
      <img class="slide" src="https://404store.com/2018/09/01/random-small-images43.png">
      <img class="slide" src="https://404store.com/2018/09/01/random-small-images43.png">
   </div>
   <input id="input" onchange = "myFunction(this)">
</div>

<script>
var myFunction=function(inputElement) {
  let x=inputElement.value;
  let imgElements=document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('slide'),(imgEle)=> {
    console.log(imgEle);
    imgEle.style.left=x+'px';
  })

}
</script>
```